# Date time Formatting for HTML Date control

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a HTML control (type="date"). Default Format is **"MM-DD-YYYY"**. But when the system level language is changed to France(or any European Language) the  date format is converting into **'DD-MM-YYYY'**. In the code end, we are expecting the **"MM-DD-YYYY"** format. ***so the issue is If a User want to select 13th of July 2019 in that case Its unable to select. Because there is no 13th Month. HTML control itself restricting the user to enter***.

Can anyone have any best approach to handle this. I have privilege to convert it into Kendo control. Still how to handle the culture will be tricky. Please suggest any better way to handle this.

Comment: Any help on this issue?

Comment: I can only help with the Kendo side, but it absolutely does support [localization](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/localization) and [various date formats](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/configuration/format)

Comment: Does Jquery Date picker will work? I have tested in my local system seems working